# FITTING A JOINT MODEL IN R Using JM

Tags: r

I am trying to use JM and failing. I keep seeing that an unassociated variable (age) is strongly associated with the outcome. Below is the toy example. Please let me know if you see an error:

```
library(JM)
####HERE IS A SAMPLE DATASET where each individual has two measurements
####n:                 number of subjects
####PERSONID:          ID for individual
####time:               time for each individual
####etime:             event time for each individual
####IS_CASE:           case status of individual
####X:                 Biomarker of interest
####AGE:               A covariate

n                  <- 100
time               <- rep(c(1,2),n)
etime              <- rep(runif(n,2,3),each=2)
PERSONID           <- as.factor(rep(sample(c((n+1):(2*n))),each=2))
AGE                <- rep(runif(n,60,80),each=2)
X                  <- rep(rnorm(n),each=2)+rnorm(2*n)
IS_CASE            <- rep(rep(c(0,1),each=2),n/2)
DATA               <- data.frame("time"=time,"etime"=etime,"PERSONID"=PERSONID,"X"=X,"IS_CASE"=IS_CASE,"AGE"=AGE)


DATA3             <- DATA[DATA$time==1,]
fitLME            <- lme(X~ time,  random = ~ time | PERSONID, data = DATA)
fitCOX            <- coxph(Surv(etime,IS_CASE) ~ AGE, data = DATA3, x = TRUE)
fitJOINT          <- jointModel(fitLME, fitCOX,timeVar = "time", method = "Cox-PH-aGH")
coef(summary(fitJOINT))$Event
```

Comment: The p-value for age is extremely small, even though she is not associated with the risk of an event.